# How does build.sbt resolve to AWS codeartifact repo?

Tags: sbt, aws-codeartifact

We recently moved to AWS codeartifact repo. We have few SBT based projects that need to get built.

Here are my global settings:

#### ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/credentials.sbt

```
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".credentials")
```

#### ~/.sbt/.credentials

```
realm=Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager
host=somedomain-1234567890.d.codeartifact.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
user=aws
password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

where `password` comes from the `CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN` from below:

```
export CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN=`aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain somedomain --domain-owner 1234567890 --query authorizationToken --output text`
```

At project level, I have

#### ./build.sbt

```
...
resolvers := Seq(
  ...
  "Private Nexus" at "https://somedomain-1234567890.d.codeartifact.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/maven/superone-snapshots",
  ...
)
...
```

However when `sbt compile` I still get:

```
[error] Unable to find credentials for [somedomain/superone-snapshots @ somedomain-1234567890.d.codeartifact.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com].
[error]   Is one of these realms misspelled for host [somedomain-1234567890.d.codeartifact.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com]:
[error]   * Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager
```

Have anyone successfully got build.sbt to resolve to AWS CodeArtificat?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The realm of your repository is `somedomain/superone-snapshots`, you have to specify that string as the realm in your ~/.sbt/.credentials file.
See https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Publishing.html#Credentials